# Secure Windows PC on the netwrok

Tags: windows

I need to expose my PC through TeamViewer. However, I don't want this PC to have any connections to my other devices in the network.

I only want for that PC to have access to the Internet all other things would be blocked (primarily viewing other PCs, devices on the network, deploying some virus, or ransomware etc.)

One option is a Virtual WLAN group, but I'm not so much into this, is there any good software that does the same?

Comment: "Secure" and "Windows" doesn't sound right in the same sentence.....

Comment: Go into Windows Services and disable "Server" and "Computer Browser"  I do this on all my PC's at home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a proper firewall..
one that is in the network.

it can limit what traffic is allowed to go to and come from any specific machine.

some possible options:

- [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) (this is opensource Firewall software, you can run on a dedicated machine, a embedded machine or in a virtual machine)
- [EdgeRouter™X](https://www.ui.com/edgemax/edgerouter-x/) (this is a router but has a good Firewall)
- [csf](https://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html) (this is a good  firewall for on the machine itself)

These options are just suggestions to start your search for the best fit, there not recommendations as is (although there all good imho)